# Google sheets conditional formatting not working as expected

Tags: google-sheets

These are the rules that I want with my conditional formatting:

- If F is within 2% of G, I want it to be green
- Otherwise, if F is higher than G I want it to be red, and lower orange

These are the formulas I have tried:

[image]

The top formula is as follows:

=(F9-G9)<=2% + (F9-G9)>=-2%

F should be orange, however it is green.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Based on what you're telling, I understand that the main formula that you want is to check the percentage of F in G and if it is greater than 0% but less than 2% then it should be green? If you try the formula you provided "=(F9-G9)<=2% + (F9-G9)>=-2%", you'll see that the result is true and that's why it is green. [Conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#:~:text=with%20conditional%20formatting-,Notes,-%3A) rules are evaluated in the order listed so this means that if the first rule found is true then it applies the format.

Comment: I want to check is the difference between the two percentages. If that is smaller than 2% I want it to be green. Can you help me write a formula for it please?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=((F9-G9)<=2%) + ((F9-G9)>=-2%)
```

or:

```
=((F9-G9)<=2%) * ((F9-G9)>=-2%)
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @K.Smith can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?